# Get user_pseudo_id from Firebase iOS SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, firebase, firebase-analytics

In Firebase Analytics, there is a user property called `user_pseudo_id`, which is automatically set by Firebase, and it seems to fit our needs.

The [doc](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7029846) says:

> The pseudonymous id (e.g., app instance ID) for the user.

but when I get Instance ID using `InstanceID.instanceID().instanceID(handler:)` it give different value from what we see in Big Query.

Any thoughts on how to get it? Thanks!

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Comment: No, we picked another id for our purpose, something like IDFA.

Comment: @OleksiiNezhyborets how did you then correlate the same user with the rest of the standard Firebase tracking? Could you retrieve somehow the `user_pseudo_id` afterwards via Big Query given the id you picked (like the IDFA you mentioned)?

Answer (score 1):

You should be using the [appInstanceID](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseanalytics/api/reference/Classes/FIRAnalytics#+appinstanceid) method of FIRAnalytics class.

```
NSString *instanceID = [FIRAnalytics appInstanceID];
NSLog(@"INSTANCE ID: %@", instanceID);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Swift 5 you can get this as follows.

```
let instanceID = Analytics.appInstanceID()
print(instanceID)
```